# AWS EMR cluster stuck in starting state

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am launching EMR cluster using AWS EMR Sdk. I am launching master and core instances in specific VPC. there are 2 subnets in that VPC both have IPs available. I am launching 1 Master and 1 core instance. Ips available in both subnets are 10-15.

When I launch EMR in subnet1 it gets launched and work fine but in subnet2 cluster get stuck in starting state . Why is it so ?

Answer (score 0):

First, refresh the display to confirm that the cluster is still in the *starting* state. It might just take a while to update.

If that does not work, **terminate** the cluster and **launch it again**. It might have been some random problem that occurred.

If the new cluster exhibits the same issue, then the problem is likely related to the second subnet. Go to the **VPC** console and examine the configuration of the two subnets, trying to find a difference between the two configurations.

They should have different IP address ranges and possibly different Availability Zones, but everything else should be identical.

**Confirm that both subnets are associated to the same Route Table**. It might be that they are configured differently, such as one public and one private subnet, which could cause the problem.

View the instances in the **EC2 management console** to determine the status of the instances. If all instance are in the *Running* state, it means that the problem lies with configuring them for EMR. If they are not in the *Running* status, you might be able to see a reason for the problem.

If all that fails, feel free to Edit your question and add more details (eg screenshots of the EMR console and of the instances in the EC2 console).

If you are subscribed to **AWS Business Support**, you can ask them to diagnose your situation.